# System.out.println not happening in console

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to System.out.println some debug statement but it won't appear on the console. I know I have the correct console open because it shows "Installing apk" and other messages when running the program. And the System.out.println statements are reached in my code. I tested it out by using Toasts and it is reached. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

When working with android you should use `android.util.Log` and look on the `Logcat` window.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Logcat` output, it should be there in `Logcat`